# How to apologize for sending wrong phone number?

Tags: email, email-etiquette, contact

I have embarked on a woodworking project and wanted to send my supervisor my contact details by email.

I didn't hear back from her for a couple days upon which I inquired about the next steps again via email.

She told me she tried to call me *multiple times*, but couldn't reach me by phone and this is where I noticed I had typoed the phone number in my previous email.

How can I own up to the fact that it was my mistake which now cost us half a week of progress and apologize professionally?

Comment: How do you normally communicate? And when she couldn't get to you via phone, why didn't she reach out by email?

Comment: Note: to whomever voted to close as "opinion-based", they are completely wrong on that one... this answer is perfectly answerable

Comment: This doesn't seem very work-related. We have a [interpersonal.se] Stack Exchange for non-work related items.

Comment: Simple accidentally just say oh sorry I mistyped it, and get on with business, dont linger. nothing more needed. Don't feel as though you alone set the project back half a week. Said person could have emailed as soon as they found the number was incorrect. Joint oops

Answer (score 18):

People make mistakes. A simple straightforward apology with the correct number should suffice.  Dont overthink it.

Answer (score 6):

"My Apologies, there was a Typo in the Phone number - here it is (correct this time) 123 4567.

Terribly sorry about the mistake"

I mean, not much more than that - it was a Typo, Typos are a thing.